# Why almost sure convergence cannot imply convergence in $L^p$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Almost sure convergence cannot imply convergence in $L^p$. However I can't find a rigorous counterexample?

Can anybody help me? Any helpful ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try $f_n(x) = 1$ if $x\in [n,n+1]$ and $f_n(x) = 0$ otherwise.

Comment: $x_n\to x$ which are not integrable

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! I think I found the nature of difference between the two modes of convergence!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the unit interval with Lebesgue measure and $f_n(x)=n^\alpha\mathbf{1}_{(0,1/n)}$, where $\alpha>0$. Whatever $\alpha$ is, this sequence converges almost everywhere to $0$. Can you find $\alpha$ such that the convergence in $\mathbb L^p$ does not hold?

Comment: I think the convergence does not hold when $\alpha \geq 1$（in a probability space）. Am i right?

Comment: For the convergence in $L^p$ the condition on $\alpha$ will depend on $p$.

Comment: oh sry i forgot $p$. then it would be $\alpha \geq \frac1p$.

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$